# Print string with ' in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, formatting

I have an array of strings `a` that I would like to print like e.g.

```
'a1','a2','a3'
```

where `a1 = a[0]`, `a2 = a[1]`, `a3 = a[2]`.

For some reason

```
printformat = ''
for i in range(3):
    printformat+=a[i]+"',"
```

prints instead

```
"a1',a2',a3',"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

print(','.join(f"'{i}'" for i in a))
```

**Output:**

```
'a1','a2','a3'
```

Answer (score 1):

With loop:

```py
printformat = "'"
for i in range(3):
    printformat += a[i] + "',"
printformat = printformat[:-1]  # Remove trailing comma
print(printformat)
```

You were exactly adding together three elements, each followed by a quote and a comma. The outer (double) quotes come from interpreter, probably, if you're doing it in REPL.

With more convenient methods:

```py
printformat = ','.join(f"'{x}'" for x in a)
print(printformat)
```